# About the fact that $f(z) = e^z$ is a covering map

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces

I am reading a proof about the complex exponential map $f:\Bbb C \to \Bbb C \setminus \{0\}, f(z)=e^z$ being a covering map and I can see that it's a surjective map, but the proof then goes on and states that for every $z =re^{i\theta} \in \Bbb C \setminus \{0\}$ we have that $$f^{-1}(z)=\{ \log r + (2k\pi +\theta)i \mid k \in \Bbb Z\}$$ from which it is easy to check $f$ is a covering map.

I don't see how it's easy to check from here? The definition of a covering map states that $f$ is a covering map if it's surjective and for any $z \in \Bbb C \setminus \{0\}$ there exists nbhd $V$ such that $f^{-1}(V)$ is a disjoint union of open sets.

Here I'm only looking at the fiber $f^{-1}(z)$ and not an open set containing $z$?

Comment: I agree. Simply using that equality doesn't give you right away that $\exp$ is a covering map.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion. You are partly correct:  the mere information that a single fiber is a discrete  collection of disjoint points is not sufficient to ensure that you have a regular covering map. However, take a closer look at the geometrical structure of these fibers. In your case you are given   $w=f(z)=e^z$ and you are using polar coordinate notation in the $w$ plane ($ w= r e^{i \theta}$). Use standard rectangular coordinates in the $z=x+i y$ plane.  Consider what happens as you first hold $r$ constant and vary $\theta$ through a small arc.  Then do the same holding $\theta$ constant and letting $r$ vary slightly. Do you see that in the $z$ plane you get a disjoint collection of congruent rectangles in the $z$ plane?

Comment: I haven't unfortunately taken complex analysis so I don't really have a geometric picture about what is happening here.